# Eclipse/Pydev indentation compressed with non-ascii characters

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I set space instead of tab for indentation,
but just as imgages show below,
in the line 43, when I insert Chinese word, the space characters is compressed.
How to solve it?
Thanks.

Befor insert Chinese word:

[image: before insert Chinese word]

After insert Chinese word:

[image: after insert Chinese word]